# How can I set layout-wrap to only apply when gt-sm?

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-material

I'm using AngularJS Material and I'm working on making my site responsive. One of the things that has to happen, is turning

- a **layout="row"** with **layout-wrap**

into

- a **layout="column"** that doesn't wrap

However, I can't find any way to make it so that it behaves like **layout-wrap-gt-sm** would. (I know that directive doesn't work, but it's a good way to explain what I would like to happen)

Is there any way to do this? If not, what would be a good alternative?
Thanks in advance.